# Why this types are not equal?

Tags: c#, types

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace App
{
  public class A<T>
  {
    public WonderfulClass<T> field;
  }

  public class WonderfulClass<T> { }

  class Programm
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Type t = typeof(A<>);

      Type t1 = t.GetField("field").FieldType;
      Type t2 = typeof(WonderfulClass<>);

      //Why t1 and t2 are different?
      Console.WriteLine(t1 == t2 ? "Equal" : "Not Equal");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you inspect the properties, you will notice:

```
t2.IsGenericTypeDefinition
true
t1.IsGenericTypeDefinition
false
```

Hence while `t2` is an actual definition, `t1` has already have it's generic type parameter applied.

Note the following:

```
t1.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == t2
true
```

Answer (score 2):

Your confusion is because you have two completely different things with the same name, T. If you said:

```
class A<T>
{
    B<T> b1;
}
class B<U> 
{
    B<U> b2;
}
```

now it should be more clear. The compile-time type of `A<T>.b1` is `B<T>`.  The compile-time type of `B<U>.b2` is `B<U>`. `B<T>` and `B<U>` are different types.